# Python Gtk3 GtkImage

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, gtk3

I've been searching quite some time but did not succeed.
In my little python3.6 application I am reading an image from a sqlite database, writing it to a png file

```
cur = self.con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT image FROM image WHERE id IS ?', str(uid))
image = cur.fetchone()[0]
fout = open('temp.png', 'wb')
fout.write(image)
fout.close()
```

only to read it back in to be displayed using

```
self.preview.set_from_file('temp.png')
```

where preview is a GtkImage created with

```
self.preview = builder.get_object('preview')
```

Is there a way to skip the writing to disk? I would much rather like to display the image straight from the db.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gtk.Image` has two methods which may be interesting. It's [set_from_pixbuf](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Image.html#Gtk.Image.set_from_pixbuf) and [set_from_surface](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/Image.html#Gtk.Image.set_from_surface).

If you choose `surface`-way, you may need to [install pycairo](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) as it's not provided with `python3-gi`. To make a surface you fetch your image and use [create_for_data](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/surfaces.html?highlight=ImageSurface#cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data).

Probably, `pixbuf`-way is simpler. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123191/4226702) answer to see, how `GdkPixbufLoader` creates GdkPixbuf from data.

Comment: Thanks to the link provided by you I manage to include the pixbuf loader correctly. Works now perfectly fine without involving writing to hdd and reading back